# Filtering a Entity Framework Context to return only certain child elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, parent-child

Good day all, super newbie to ASP.NET, Entity Framework and the like.  Very versed in straight line programming, so I am first having to try and forget the old way before the new way can sink in.

I am developing an app that will track a FLEET item (parent) and all of its FLEETEVENT items (child). The two are linked via a FleetId field.

I can use: `Fleet fleet = db.Fleets.Find(id);` and it returns the parent record matching the id variable, and ALL of its child elements.

What I am trying to do is to return ONLY the child elements where FLEETEVENT.STATUS == True

I have tried using LINQ expressions and DataLoadOptions.AssosiateWith, but I get all records with the AssociateWith and conversion errors trying to use the LINQ expressions.

I am thinking it should not be TOO hard to do this, but I am stuck in my old way of thinking.

Code snipets are as follows:

Connector model:

```
public class FleetContext : DbContext
{
    public FleetContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Fleet> Fleets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FleetEvent> FleetEvents { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FleetConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FleetEventConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Parent model:

```
public class Fleet : IObjectWithState
{
    public Fleet()
    {
        FleetEvents = new List<FleetEvent>();
        Status = true;
    }

    public System.Guid FleetId { get; set; }
    public string FleetType { get; set; }
    public string FleetNum { get; set; }
    public string FleetMake { get; set; }
    public string FleetModel { get; set; }
    public int FleetYear { get; set; }

    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }

    public virtual List<FleetEvent> FleetEvents { get; set; }
}
```

Child model:

```
public class FleetEvent : IObjectWithState
{
    public System.Guid FleetEventId { get; set; }
    public DateTime FleetEventDate { get; set; }
    public string FleetEventType { get; set; }
    public string FleetEventDesc { get; set; }

    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public System.Guid FleetId { get; set; }
    public Fleet Fleet { get; set; }

    public ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }
}
```

Using LINQ, this is the code in my controller that I am using:

```
var result = from f in db.Fleets
                     join fe in db.FleetEvents
                         on f.FleetId equals fe.FleetId
                     where ((f.FleetId == id) && (fe.Status == true))
                     select new { f, fe };

        Fleet fleet = result.ToList();
```

I have verified that the LINQ syntax is correct via LinqPad returning the results I expected.  But when I use it in code, I get conversion errors in the Fleet fleet line of code.

Any information to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide the specific error message?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, in Entity framework you should learn how to query using navigation properties and avoid joins at any cost.

Here is the sample,

```
// return all FleetEvents where FleetEvent.Status = true for fleetID = n...
var result = db.FleetEvents
                 .Where(x=> x.Status == true && x.FleetID = id)
                 .Select( x=> new {
                        Fleet = x.Fleet,
                        FleetEvent = x
                     } );

// however result is of anonymous type, so you get Fleet and 
// FleetEvent both as properties of result
```

If you want to return all fleets with any child having Status = true

```
var fleets = db.Fleets
               .Where( x=> x.FleetID == id && 
                           x.FleetEvents.Any(f=> f.Status == true));

// fleets is now and enumerable with all fleets with atleast 
// one child having Status=true
```

If you want to return all fleets with all children having Status = true

```
var fleets = db.Fleets
               .Where( x=> x.FleetID == id )
               .Select( x=> new {
                    Fleet = x,
                    FleetEvents = x.FleetEvents.Where(f=> f.Status == true)
               });

// here you have once again Anonymous type with Fleet and all FleetEvents 
// with Status = true
```

Comment: Akash,

Thanks.  After doing some additional research, I did run onto code very similar to this.  Were I fail was casting the anonymous type back to the class type, as code further down requires it.

I did, however find that the following works to pull items into the actual Fleet class:

            Fleet fleet = db.Fleets
                            .Where(f => f.FleetId == id)
                            .Include(fe => fe.FleetEvents)
                            .Single();

But the minute I try to change the .Include line to:

         .Include(fe => fe.FleetEvents.Where(fe => fe.Status))

Comment: I get the following error:

The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path

I just didnt think it should be this difficult.  =\

Comment: You can't cast anonymous type to class type, you have to use Select and get whole object as one of the property. You can't have where expression in include path. What you want is the last query, you will get Fleet and FleetEvents both. But as anonymous object, and you can access it with Fleet and FleetEvents properties.

Comment: Ok. I am beginning to get the idea.  What I was trying to do is avoid having to pull all the children over from the database then filter them before I sent them to the client in the view, as after some time, the number of children can grow to be quite large.

Or, am I looking at this wrong and am thinking that this will have too much of an impact on the sql server?

Comment: In that case, you query parent and child separately, and use paging. Single query is only useful for smaller datasets only.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Fleet is a class, not a List<>().  So you will fail when calling ToList().
Also selecting f, fe does not a Fleet make.  :)  To select a class you would specifically something similar to this:

```
select new MyClass()
{
      MyField = f.Field,
      MyThingy = fe.thingy
}
```

What you may want to do instead is something like this:

```
Fleet fleet = new Fleet()
{
      FleetId = results.FleetId,
      FleetEventDate = results.FleetEventDate,
      ...
}
```

The hardest part will be populating the list inside the object.  But you could enumerate through the fe instances and add each to the List of FleetEvents.